# Difference between Convergence and Sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Im just trying to understand the concepts of convergence and sum of a serie for my calc course but i dont seem to know the difference between the value where a serie converges and the value of the sums, are both the same ?

if a serie converges to 0 does that mean that his sum is 0 too?

Comment: Consider $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$. We have $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ but  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ diverges, or "goes to infinity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence $a_n$ (with $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$) is convergent if and only if it is a Cauchy-sequence. In words a Cauchy-sequence is a sequence whose elements become arbitrarily close to each other as the sequence progresses, for example (as stated above: $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$) . The limit of such a sequence is unique (in $\mathbb{R}$).

Now the convergence of a sum is a bit more tedious. For $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ to be a convergent sum, necessarily its summands $a_n$ must form a zero sequence, i.e. $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$. But the convergence of $a_n$ to $0$ doesn't automatically imply, that the sum is also convergent. To decide the latter you can use the Cauchy Criteria:

> A sum of the form $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ is convergent, if
> $\forall \varepsilon >0, \: \exists N(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall m,n > N(\varepsilon): \: |a_n - a_m| < \varepsilon$

The limit of the sequence and the sum don't have to be equal. For example look at the following sequence:
Let $|q| < 1$ and
$$a_k = q^k, \: \text{for} \: k \geq 0$$
$$a_k = 1, \: \text{for} \: k=-1$$

Since $|q| < 1$, we know that $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} q^k = 0$ and since $a_k, \: k>-1$ is the geometric sequence, we know that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k = \frac{1}{1-q}$

$$\Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k=-1}^{\infty} a_k = a_{-1} + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} q^k= 1 + \frac{1}{1-q}$$